# ASP.NET MVC Uploading file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to upload picture to a folder. I have already try all  answers here.
Here is my code:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFile uploadFile)
{
    if (uploadFile != null)
    {
        string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName);
        string Path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/" + ImageName);
        // save image in folder
        uploadFile.SaveAs(Path);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "Quizs", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data " }))
{
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="uploadFile" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
}
```

When I submit that form i get NULL in Controller (uploadFile is null). 
Please help me and tell me what is wrong.

Thank you

Comment: It should be `HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile`. You also have an extra space in `new { enctype = "multipart/form-data " }`

Comment: Thanks! Problem was extra space in "multipart/form-data ". Thanks all for answers!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks all for answers! Problem was extra space in

```
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data " }
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be "HttpPostedFileBase" instead of "HttpPostedFile"..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with routing. you must create a model that has a property of type `HttpPostedFileBase` (not `HttpPostedFile`) and name of uploadFile, and set your action methods argument to that model, a model like this:

```
public class FileSaveModel
{
       public HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile {get; set;}
}
```

and then change your actions argument to:

```
public ActionResult UploadImage(FileSaveModel model)
```

Comment: Routing has nothing to do with it. And although using a model is better, its not necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest following Code:

**My View Page:**

Here,I'm using model property for Uploading Image Called `"uploadFile"`.

```
@model Users
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "Quizs", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <input type="file"  id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile">
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.uploadFile)
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        }
```

**My Model Class:**

This is my model class which has a property called `"uploadFile"` as `HttpPostedFileBase`  DataType.

```
public partial class Users
    {
       public HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile { get; set; }
    }
```

**My Controller Page:**

Here,I'm using Users model class as input param which has my property and using `UploadUserAvatar()` method for Uploading a image in folder in particular path called  `"~/Content/Images"`

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Registration(Users user)
        {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
            UploadUserAvatar(user.uploadFile);
            return View();
          }       
        }
  protected void UploadUserAvatar(HttpPostedFileBase image)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = image;
            if (file != null)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images")))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"));
                string _fileName = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                string _path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/"), _fileName);
                file.SaveAs(_path);

            }
      }
```

Comment: Why do you suggest a completely different code without any explanations instead of helping the OP to solve his problem?

Comment: @UweKeim,Thanks for your suggestion,I update my answer with explanations.